# Is it possible to download all mp3s from a domain or URL?

Tags: bash, mp3, wget, url

I'd like to download all mp3s from the blog [pinchy&friends](http://www.pinchyandfriends.com/). I tried the script

```
for mp3 in "http://www.pinchyandfriends.com/dl.php?mp3=*.mp3"; do
    wget "http://www.pinchyandfriends.com/dl.php?mp3=${mp3}.mp3"
    sleep 5
done
```

But all that results in is an attempt to download the literal `http://www.pinchyandfriends.com/dl.php?mp3=*.mp3`. Am I misunderstanding something about the script I wrote and/or is there a better way to do what I'm attempting? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This won't work like this. A webpage is not a file-system where you can do globbing (using '*' and '?') from a single URL-String. You would need to download the html-file (with wget) from that URL and then follow the links from there which is non-trivial. You need to account for all kinds of links, like relative links and possibly also stuff loaded later with javascript.

Comment: Can you add why you want to do this by script? Maybe we can find you a easier alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about qlobbing. I see now what I was doing wrong. It looks like Krzysztof Rosiński solved my problem here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109256/is-it-possible-to-download-all-mp3s-from-a-domain-or-url/21109556?noredirect=1#21109556`

Comment: Grrr. You cross-poster!

Comment: That is an excellent answer you got on SO, though!

Answer (score 1):

While don.joey's answer directly deals with your question about wget, it's worth noting that there are a plethora of browser plug-ins that can also do this for you.  The ones I've used are [linky](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/linky/), [downloadThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/), [FlashGot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/)and [SnapLinksPlus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/SnapLinksPlus/).

That said, becoming proficient in curl and wget commands is never a bad thing.  ;-)

Comment: I'd like to add [jDownloader](https://launchpad.net/~jd-team/+archive/jdownloader) which has been a great tool for all my mass-downloading needs for some time. Also +1 for "becoming proficient in curl and wget commands"

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
wget -r -P /save/location -A mp3 http://www.domain.com
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602153/how-do-i-use-wget-to-download-all-images-into-a-single-folder)

Comment: Since the default length is 5, won't this recurse? I think, it must be `wget -r -l 2 -P /save/location -A mp3 http://www.domain.com`.

Comment: When I run that, the only thing it attempts is a download of `www.pinchyandfriends.com/index.html`. It looks like the recursive search doesn't work as intended for some reason.

Comment: I see what you mean. The links on the home page are js-based. Hmm. Not sure how to do this then.

Comment: I wanted to delete my post, but I'll keep it here for reference' sake. The accepted answer on this cross-post can be found on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109256/is-it-possible-to-download-all-mp3s‌​-from-a-domain-or-url/21109556?noredirect=1#21109556.